# Unable to import Google Project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to add Firebase Cloud Messaging to an existing Android app that is currently published on the Google Play Store.

However, when I log into the Firebase console and select 'IMPORT GOOGLE PROJECT' I don't see any projects come up. None of the Android apps I have on the Google Play Store show up.

Is an Android app not the same thing as a Google Project? Should I just create a new Firebase project?

TIA

Comment: You have to create new Project using you App's package name on Firebase. you can't Import project and long as you have't crated one on Firebase.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit when I create a new project it asks for Project Name, but no place to put package name like com.company.appname

Comment: yes give project name and create project. once you are done. you will get option to add firebase to android application. there you will be able to specify you package name

Comment: AFAIK, the *Import Google Project* only displays the Projects from your Developers Console. If you have the same project, it should display it. If not, I would suggest reaching out to Firebase/Google Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Import Google Projects` refers to importing existing Google Cloug projects 
(from https://console.google.com).

This is important if you application is already using some Google Cloud API, like Google Cloud Messaging, and you now want to use Firebase.

If you don't are not already using a Google Cloud project, don't worry and simply create a new Firebase Project.

If you have existing Google Cloud projects, but they don't show up in the import menu, please contact Firebase Support.